# How to reproduce this font?

Tags: fonts

I am unable to reproduce the following font/style in a tikz picture:

[image]

This is my code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage[mathcal]{euscript}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, 
    minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [block] (A) {$\mathbf{G}_{\mathcal{IP}}+\mathbf{u}_{\mathcal{F}}\mathbf{G}_{\mathcal{FP}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which generates

[image]

How to fix this?

---

Update:
without `euscript`:

[image]

Comment: Get rid of `\usepackage[mathcal]{euscript}` or at least get rid of `[mathcal]`

Comment: It changes the font but still different from the one in the question. I could not upload the image due to  the reputation limit.

Comment: The subscripts [look like Zapf Chancery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XONN.png)

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle I noticed that as well. But how to change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the subscripts look like Zapf Chancery, there are several clones of that available with TeX setup, perhaps

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage{urwchancal}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, 
    minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [block] (A) {$\mathbf{G}_{\mathcal{IP}}+\mathbf{u}_{\mathcal{F}}\mathbf{G}_{\mathcal{FP}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replaced `euscript` with `\usepackage[cal=zapfc]{mathalfa}`